# Why the inode value of shadow file changes?

Tags: files, inode, shadow

I created a hard link for the shadow file. For removing the passwd of the user I opened the shadow file in vi editor and removed the encrypted passwd and then saved. The inode value of the shadow file was changed. Then I updated the passwd of the user and again the inode value of the shadow file changed. 
Why the inode of the shadow file changes when it is edited/updated?

Comment: Why do you need a hardlink to `shadow`?

Comment: The inode value is intimately related to the hardlink(s).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The usual implementation of password changing involves hardlinking `/etc/shadow` to `/etc/stmp` (or some similar name; `link()` being atomic on local filesystems, this constitutes a kind of lock file mechanism), writing out a new one to a temporary file, then renaming the original `/etc/shadow` to `/etc/shadow-` or similar and renaming the temporary to `/etc/shadow`.  This is done for robustness:  at all times the original `shadow` file, unmodified, still exists and can be recovered easily even if the power fails at just the wrong time or something equally bad (unless it destroys the entire disk).

Comment: On my Fedora system, which uses the `passwd` package, it creates `/etc/.pwd.lock` as the lock file, writes the new contents to `/etc/nshadow`, and then renames the files.  And with `shadow-utils`, it seems the lock file would be `/etc/passwd.lock` and write the temporary file to `/etc/shadow+`, but the idea is the same.